# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Пытаюсь втроить Spring Security в springMVC-приложение, но вылетает ошибка создания бина, хотя вроде все должно быть нормально.

Полный текст ошибки 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.spring.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Упоминаемые в ошибке классы:
SecurityConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImp userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin()
                // указываем страницу с формой логина
                .loginPage("/login")
                //указываем логику обработки при логине
                .successHandler(new LoginSuccessHandler())
                // указываем action с формы логина
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                // Указываем параметры логина и пароля с формы логина
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                // даем доступ к форме логина всем
                .permitAll();

        http
                .logout()
                // разрешаем делать логаут всем
                .permitAll()
                // указываем URL логаута
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "POST"))
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                //выклчаем кроссдоменную секьюрность (на этапе обучения неважна)
                .and().csrf().disable();

        http
                // делаем страницу регистрации недоступной для авторизированных пользователей
                .authorizeRequests()
                //страницы аутентификаци доступна всем
                .antMatchers("/login", "/").anonymous()
                // защищенные URL
                .antMatchers("/users/**").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

UserService.java

```java
public interface UserService {
    Optional<User> getUserById(Long id);
    void deleteUser(Long id);
    void updateUser(User user);
    List<User> listUsers();
    void createUser(User user);
}
```

UserServiceImp.java

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImp implements UserDetailsService, UserService{


    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Optional<User> getUserById(Long id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(Long id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> listUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void createUser(User user) {
        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(new UserRole(1L, "ROLE_USER")));
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

> [ссылка на гит](https://github.com/relizerel/Spring-Security.git)

Comment: На UserRepository вешали аннотацию @Repository?

Comment: Да, аннотацию повесил. Ошибка изменилась, но суть осталась той же - прога пытается подтянуть UserRepository, но nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.spring.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Comment: а кто у вас сканирует аннотации то вообще? + Spring Boot нельзя использовать?

Comment: В этом вся проблема, что задача состоит в использовании MVC... аннотации сканирует класс, конфигурирующий MVC

Comment: добавьте коммит с добавленными аннотациями

Comment: Да, извините. Запушил изменения

Comment: В dataconfig добавьте ещё @EnableJpaRepositories("com.spring")

Comment: Добавил аннотацию, и теперь получаю ошибку nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2a0be6b7'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available. Что это за бин непонятный я сказать не могу. Папку target чистил, от предыдущих компиляций ничего не подтянулось

Comment: надо пометить ваш бин который возвращает EntityManagerFactory как     @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")

Comment: но если честно, каждую из этих ошибок, уже можно было загуглить, считаю данный вопрос можно закрыть

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) на момент написания Вашего коммента я уже добавил название к бину и в данный момент гуглю следующие ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо комментаторам, благодаря вам я смог найти за что зацепиться и в итоге решить вопрос.
изменения, которые я внес в программу:

1. Добавил аннотации @Repository к классу UserRepository
2. Добавил аннотацию @EnableJpaRepositories("com.spring")  класс конфигурации БД
3. Изменил аннотацию @Bean в методе entityManager'а на @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
4. Изменил аннотацию @EnableTransactionManagement в конфиге БД на @EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)